# Organizing pattern implementations

Tags: design-patterns, project-organization

We have started to use a few patterns in work, most notably, Event Aggregation and Specification. Since these implementations are usually consumed by a large number of projects we are trying to find a place to put them. Our current location is:

```
 ProductName.Core.Patterns.Specification
 ProductName.Core.Patterns.EventAggregator
```

But this would not led itself well to alternate base implementations of a given pattern. Before we commit to the structure above I was wondering if people could share how they folded pattern implementations into their projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, its always good to make packages or folders based on components/modules in the project. If you already have packages for these functionality then you can just put your stucture there. Its your design document that will tell which pattern is being used in which component.